# Using :not() in Less deep nested

Tags: css, reference, nested, less

In a deep nested container I would like to check if `body` has not a given class and and apply some styling on this element.

Here is what I tried with Less but it does not work.

```
.node1{ 
  .node2{
    &-index-1{}
    &-index-2 {
       &:not(body.some-class){
          //apply changes on &-index-2
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can by appending the `&` (parent selector) at the end instead of using it at the start.

```css
.node1{ 
  .node2{
    &-index-1{
        color: blue;
    }
    &-index-2 {
       body:not(.some-class) &{ // reason for change of :not() is explained below.
          color: red;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

One thing to note is that the CSS `:not()` selector currently doesn't accept complex selectors. It will accept only simple selectors and so the selector should be written like `body:not(.some-class) &`.

```css
.node1 .node2-index-1 {
  color: blue;
}
body:not(.some-class) .node1 .node2-index-2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='node1'>
    <div class='node2-index-1'>
      Index 1
    </div>
    <div class='node2-index-2'>
      Index 2
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

So just apply rules to body:

```
body{
    .node1{ 
        .node2{
            &-index-1{}
        }
    }

    &:not(.some-class) {
        .node1{ 
            .node2{
                &-index-1{}
                &-index-2 {
                  //apply changes on &-index-2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```